# R user-defined function called but not running

Tags: r, function, tibble

I am new to R, and I am trying to create a user-defined function and run it inside a for loop. The function is defined in the same script before it is called. However, when the function is called, the code inside the function doesn't run. No syntax errors occur.

Here is the function definition:

```
placeInVector <- function(subjectID, morpho) {
  if (morpho == "Alg") {
    algVec <- c(algVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "Anem") {
    anemVec <- c(anemVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "Barn") {
    barnVec <- c(barnVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "Biv") {
    bivVec <- c(bivVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "BrBryo") {
    brbryoVec <- c(brbryoVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "ColTuni") {
    coltuniVec <- c(coltuniVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "EnBryo") {
    enbryoVec <- c(enbryoVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "Nothing") {
    nothingVec <- c(nothingVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "SolTuni") {
    soltuniVec <- c(soltuniVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "Spng") {
    spngVec <- c(spngVec, subjectID)
  }
  else if (morpho == "TubeWm") {
    tubewmVec <- c(tubewmVec, subjectID)
  }
}
```

Here is where the function is called later on in the script:

```
for (subject in subjects$SubjectID) {
  currentRow <- finalIDs %>% 
    filter(SubjectID == subject)
    morphoID <- as.character(currentRow$FinalIDs1)
  if (morphoID != "NONE") {
    placeInVector(subject, morphoID)
  }
}
```

Note: all of the vectors referenced in the function definition (algVec, anemVec, etc.) are defined as empty vectors.

Comment: You need to learn what function are and how to return from the function. Your function will never run. You are returning at the very begnning

Comment: I put that in there to test something and meant to take it out. Thanks

Comment: Add some demo data to replicate your function please.

Comment: Even with that, you function will not do anything. You need to learn about R environments, memory handling and copy-on-modify semantics

Comment: Your function is still doing nothing. For example, `if (morpho == "Alg")` it creates `algVec` and then does nothing wth it. At the end of the function, this variable is thrown away. Hence nothing has been done/ modified

Comment: algVec and all of the others are global variables, and are defined outside of the function. Does it still throw away the changes?

Comment: `dput()` your variables or include as random ones. It is the only way to help you.

Comment: Yes. It still throws away the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to add elements to vectors. Because I don't have a reproducible example, I will use my own. Here, `add_to_vector` adds elements to `a` and `b`:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c("a","b")

add_to_vector <- function(vec, to_add){
  vec <- c(vec, to_add)
  return(vec)
}

a <- add_to_vector(a, 3)
b <- add_to_vector(b, "c")
```

Hopefully, this gives you an idea of how R works.

**Output**

```
> a
[1] 1 2 3
> b
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```